# Angular Cross Component Service

Tags: javascript, angular, service

I am fairly new with Angular and I am trying to find my way through this issue.  I have looked at various posts here and on the web but i am finding either the solution doesn't quite fit my needs or I am unsure how to adapt the solution.

I have a main data grid where the user can select 1 => 1+n records.  when they select the records and hit the details button, a new page loads through angular routing to a new view where the user can then view each detailed record through next/prev buttons.

because the user can select a number of records and the details page will show more data than what is just on the grid i dont want to send all of the data associated with each record.  What I want to do is take just the record id(s) as an array and pass it to a service.  this would be the only interaction the grid page has with the service - the initial passing of id.

```
    this.selectedKeys.forEach(x =>
         this.selectedIds.push(x.id)
    )
```

after this array is passed to the service, i would call the router to navigate to the details page and display the FIRST record in the selectedIds array

```
    this.router.navigate(["details/", this.selectedIds[0].id], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

I can do all of that.  my problem lies in navigating from one detail page to the next or going to the previous page.  My end goal would be to pass this array of id(s) from the gird page to the details page and using the service to maintain that object of arrays and to use the ids to query my database to properly display the details of the record.  Then, if i want to go to the next record, i can press the next record button and the process repeats but using the new record id.

i tried my hand at a few hacky ways to do this.  One being passing the ids to the service and utilizing the service to build an array of page data that included the current page, nextpage, previous page references and using counters to determine which page i was on and corralate that back to the page data array.  i was then running into an issue with not disposing of the data properly and running into invalid references to data that i never selected but had previously.

I believe the proper way to do this would be to use subjects and/or behavior subjects.  I just dont know how to implement that.  its quite possible either this is so easy that i dont see it or this is not possible with subjects/behaviorsubjects but can be done in a different way.

anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

SERVICE

```
    interface pageSetUpParametersArray
  { 
    currentPageLink: string,
    currentPageIndex: number,
    nextPageDisabled: boolean, 
    previousPageDisabled: boolean, 
    nextPageLink: string, 
    previousPageLink: string 
  }

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService implements Resolve<Events> {

  constructor(
    private dataService: BaseDataService, 
    private router: Router) 
    { }


    private selectedIdsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Array<number>>([]);
    selectedIdsSource$ = this.selectedIdsSource.asObservable();
    _localSelectedIds: number[] = []
    currentDataIndex: number = 0;
    nextPageDis: boolean = false;
    prevPageDis: boolean = false;
    pageParamsArray: pageSetUpParametersArray[] = []

   sendEventIds(ids: number[]) {
    console.log('got event ids: ', ids);
    this._localSelectedIds = ids;
    console.log('got event _localSelectedIds: ', this._localSelectedIds);
   }

   pageSetUp = async() => {
      
    this.pageParamsArray.splice(0, this.pageParamsArray.length);
    this.currentDataIndex = 0;
    this.nextPageDis = false;
    this.prevPageDis = false;

    for(let x = 0; x <= this._localSelectedIds.length-1; x++) {
      if ( x == 0 || ( x === 0 && (this._localSelectedIds.length-1) == 2) ) {
        this.pageParamsArray.push({ 
          currentPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x]}`,
          currentPageIndex: x,
          nextPageDisabled: false, 
          previousPageDisabled: true,
          nextPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x+1]}`,
          previousPageLink: ""
          })
      } 
      else if ( x === this._localSelectedIds.length -1 ){
        this.pageParamsArray.push({ 
          currentPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x]}`,
          currentPageIndex: x,
          nextPageDisabled: true, 
          previousPageDisabled: false,
          nextPageLink: "",
          previousPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x-1]}`
          })
      }
      else {
        this.pageParamsArray.push({ 
          currentPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x]}`,
          currentPageIndex: x,
          nextPageDisabled: false, 
          previousPageDisabled: false,
          nextPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x+1]}`,
          previousPageLink: `/details/${this._localSelectedIds[x-1]}`
          })
      }

      console.log('pageParamsArray: ', this.pageParamsArray)
    }
  }

   /**
     * controls the next detail record button
     * used to see where the user is in the array of ids and determine if
     * the next button is disabled and keeps the current page index
     * 
     * @returns the link used to move to the next detail record
     */
    getNextLink() {

      console.log('current data index getNext: ', this.currentDataIndex)
      console.log('pageParamsArray getNext: ', this.pageParamsArray)
      let link = this.pageParamsArray[this.currentDataIndex].nextPageLink
      let next: number;
      let prev: number;

      if (this.currentDataIndex === 0) {
        next = this.currentDataIndex + 1;
        if (this._localSelectedIds.length > 1) {
          prev = this.currentDataIndex + 1;
        } else {
          prev = this.currentDataIndex;
        }
        
      }
      else if (this.currentDataIndex === this._localSelectedIds.length-1) {
        next = this._localSelectedIds.length - 1;
        prev = this.currentDataIndex - 1;
      }
      else {
        next = this.currentDataIndex + 1 ;
        prev = this.currentDataIndex;
      }

      this.nextPageDis = this.pageParamsArray[next].nextPageDisabled
      this.prevPageDis = this.pageParamsArray[prev].previousPageDisabled

      this.currentDataIndex = this.currentDataIndex + 1;

      return link;
    }

    /**
     * controls the previous detail record button
     * used to see where the user is in the array of ids and determine if
     * the previous button is disabled and keeps the current page index
     * 
     * @returns the link used to move to the previous detail record
     */
    getPreviousLink() {

      console.log('current data index getPrev: ', this.currentDataIndex)
      let link = this.pageParamsArray[this.currentDataIndex].previousPageLink
      let next: number;
      let prev: number;

      if (this.currentDataIndex == 0) {
        // next = this.currentDataIndex + 1;
        // prev = this.currentDataIndex;
        next = this.currentDataIndex + 1;
        prev = this.currentDataIndex;


      }
      else if (this.currentDataIndex === this._localSelectedIds.length-1) {
        next = this.currentDataIndex - 1;
        prev = this.currentDataIndex - 1;
      }
      else {
        next = this.currentDataIndex;
        prev = this.currentDataIndex - 1;
      }

      this.nextPageDis = this.pageParamsArray[next].nextPageDisabled
      this.prevPageDis = this.pageParamsArray[prev].previousPageDisabled

      //update the index to what it will be
      this.currentDataIndex = this.currentDataIndex - 1;
      
      return link;
    }
```

GRID

```
  onDetails() {
    this.selectedKeys.forEach(x =>
        this.selectedIds.push(x.id)
    )

    this.eventDetailsService.sendEventIds(this.selectedIds)

    this.eventDetailsService.pageSetUp();

    this.router.navigate(["details/", this.selectedIds[0]], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

DETAILS

```
ngOnInit() {
    // sets initial disabled/enabled of buttons
    this.eventDetailsService.nextPageDis = this.eventDetailsService.pageParamsArray[this.eventDetailsService.currentDataIndex].nextPageDisabled;
    this.eventDetailsService.prevPageDis = this.eventDetailsService.pageParamsArray[this.eventDetailsService.currentDataIndex].previousPageDisabled;


    this.route.data.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((result) => {
      this.entity = result.Events.value[0] as Events;
    });

    this.editRestorationDataSource.data = editRestorationData;
    this.editRepairDataSource.data = editRepairData;
  }
    
  onCancel(): void {
    this.navigateBackToGrid();
  }

    /**
   * moves to next page of details
   * builds the navigiation link
   */
  nextPage() {
    this.router.navigate([this.eventDetailsService.getNextLink()])
  }
  
  /**
   * moves to previous page of details
   *    * builds the navigiation link
   */
  previousPage() {
    this.router.navigate([this.eventDetailsService.getPreviousLink()])
  }
```

Comment: First thing I noticed: “ when they select the records and hit the details button, a new page opens” - do you mean it navigates (using Angular routing) to another view (i.e. your list view is gone) - or do you literally mean opening a new page (a new tab in the browser or a window.open)?

Comment: good call.  through angular routing - i made the edit

Comment: Rightio. So you have a grid component that loads an overview of records and you have a detail component that can load the details of an id? Your approach is quite solid I think. The service just keeps an array of selected ids (set by the grid) and the detail page reads that array, and fetches the first id from that array, and builds a paginator for the other ids in the array. Idon’t really see an issue..?

Comment: i guess my issue is 2 fold
1) is this the best way to do this?
2) i cant seem to dispose of the paginator data properly.  If i do it in onDispose, the next time runs it breaks.  if i dont do it then i seem to maintain the last run.  so if i selected 5 ids ill see 5 records.  but if i go back to the main grid and select 4 or less, ill still see 5

my issue may not be associated with the original question but a logic question.  let me add more real code

Comment: Mm.. that sounds simply like your not maintaining your array correctly. One tip, use immutability, so don’t push to the array, but create a new array every time with spreading. I don’t really see a need for observables here either as the grid and the detail page never exist at the same time. This question is getting dangerous though as it is opinion based which SO doesn’t like :-)

Comment: so replace this

this.selectedKeys.forEach(x =>
        //this.selectedIds.push(x.id)
    )

with this

this.selectedKeys.forEach(x =>
        this.selectedIds = [...this.selectedIds, x.id]
    )
??

Comment: Yes and no (the spread is fine). I’m not sure how this is triggered from the template, but the forEach seems unnecessary. It depends on if you have a selected kinda state on your grid data.. like an x.id, also an x.selected. If so, things become a lot easier and more predictable.

Comment: the for each is because there are other values with each selected row that I do not need so i need to loop through them and only grab the id.  This seems to be working so far.  i still have some more tests to do but the tests right now are very promising.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Only one row is ever selected or deselect at a time though so why is there a loop?.. but as I said - I’m not sure how you implemented that.. PS: this.selectedIds = this.selectedKeys.map( (item: any) => item.id ) is a bit cleaner.